# Convert USB3 to WIFI

Tags: usb, communication, wifi

What methods could be used to convert USB3 communication to WiFi, when there is no access to the device's OS?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, is the word "simple" quite appropriate?

Comment: Please can you narrow your question to a single, answerable design question.

Comment: @Andyaka "simple" refers to the digital camera, not the operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a USB over Ethernet box and plug that into a wifi router/access point.  Or get a small single-board computer with a wifi card.  These are basically the only two options.  However, you will not be able to get full USB 3.0 bandwidth over wifi; it doesn't have sufficient bandwidth.

Edit: take a look at http://usbip.sourceforge.net/ .

Comment: Thanks. Do you think using a FPGA and a WiFi component is not a good way to solve this?

Comment: Well, you could, but it would be extremely complicated.  You would basically have to do what a USB to Ethernet box does already, and you would have to use a rather hefty FPGA and USB 3 interface chips, do a custom controlled impedance board, etc.  Not to mention the other end of the wifi link.  I presume implementing that in software would be simpler than another FPGA, but then you would also have to figure out how to emulate a USB device in your OS of choice, etc., etc.  And you would still not be able to go at the full USB 3 rate.

Comment: For reference: USB 3.0 is 5 Gbps full duplex, wifi is (currently) max 1 Gbps half-duplex, so absolute best case you can only use 1/10 of the USB 3.0 bandwidth.

Comment: Ok, I understand this limit. What are the advantages of using the Ethernet solution over the SBC solution? And what do you mean by figuring out how to emulate a USB device in the OS? If I use a SBC with a USB input, wouldn't the OS know how to handle it?

Comment: SBC would decouple the issue.  You can run software on the computer to, say, transcode the video from the camera to something that you can stream more easily over wifi.  If you want to build a custom solution with an FPGA, then I suppose you would have to decide what level to operate on.  Either you can write code on the FPGA to communicate with the device, extract the data you're interested in, and stream that (i.e. what you could do with a SBC, except on an FPGA) or you can try to make it look like it is connected to a computer, in which case it needs to be emulated on the remote computer.

Comment: (this is what the USB over Ethernet boards do - they come with software that emulates a USB device so the OS can attach the corresponding driver, then all data and commands get passed over the network to the USB over Ethernet box which sends them to the device)